# Is it possible to set the user's home directory to the /mnt/disk folder?

Tags: linux, disk-usage

The server capacity in our lab is small. When we create a directory, we always use `useradd -d /home/username`. According to the result of `df -h`, the capacity of `/dev/sda1` is too small. So every once in a while, the lab will notify us to delete something. Or move the file to `/mnt/disk`.

Is it possible to use `useradd -d /mnt/disk/username username` to create a user? If this works, is the file in `/dev/vdb1`?

```
$df -h
    Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    udev             23G     0   23G   0% /dev
    tmpfs           4.6G  1.1M  4.6G   1% /run
    /dev/vda1        99G   92G  2.5G  98% /
    tmpfs            23G  672K   23G   1% /dev/shm
    tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
    /dev/vdb1       492G   98G  369G  21% /mnt/disk
    tmpfs           4.6G  860K  4.6G   1% /run/user/1022
    tmpfs           4.6G   44K  4.6G   1% /run/user/1013
    tmpfs           4.6G  196K  4.6G   1% /run/user/1000
    tmpfs           4.6G  172K  4.6G   1% /run/user/1018
    tmpfs           4.6G   68K  4.6G   1% /run/user/1017
    tmpfs           4.6G  324K  4.6G   1% /run/user/1025
    tmpfs           4.6G   40K  4.6G   1% /run/user/1023
    tmpfs           4.6G  216K  4.6G   1% /run/user/1024
```

Comment: You are mixing block device files (`/dev/vdb1`) and their respective mount points (`/mnt/disk`) in your question. Also you mention adding directories but give a command to create users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it is possible, but the mountpoint is badly chosen. `/mnt` is used for removable devices. The disk containing the users' home directories need to be mounted at all times, or the users won't be able to use the system.

Comment: Here’s [the reference for `/mnt`](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s12.html#purpose13) — strictly speaking it’s for temporary mounts, [removable devices go on `/media`](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s11.html) now. This is really up to the administrator though, if `/mnt/disk` is permanent then using it is fine.

Comment: One thing to look out for is _assumptions_ about where users' home directories are. Some scripts may look for users' home directories under `/home`.

Comment: There's absolutely no harm in having a home directory at `/mnt/something`, in fact there are zero limitations of where it could be. Its path should consist of ascii characters, dash, dot and numbers - that's it.

Comment: You might also run into a problem if you have `selinux` in enforcing mode. I have not had to do this in a while but `semanage fcontext -a -e /home /mnt` should get you going but may also cause other problems if you have multiple mounts under `/mnt`.